# Date difference in Java 23 hours day

Tags: java, date

I have to calculate the difference between to dates, I have found a way but I have this strange result, Am I missing something?

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
    DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm");
    long result = format.parse("2012-03-25 24:00").getTime() - format.parse("2012-03-25 00:00").getTime();
    System.out.println("Difference in hours: " + result/(1000*60*60));
    result = format.parse("2012-03-26 24:00").getTime() - format.parse("2012-03-26 00:00").getTime();
    System.out.println("Difference in hours: " + result/(1000*60*60));
}
```

This is the result:
Difference in hours: 23
Difference in hours: 24

Thanks for the advices, now I'm using the Joda libray, I have this question, when I calculate the difference in this way:

```
DateTime  begin = new DateTime("2012-03-25T00:00+01:00");
DateTime  end = new DateTime("2012-03-26T00:00+01:00");
Hours m = Hours.hoursBetween(begin, end);
```

If I use this way to calculate the hours I get 24 hours (because the DST is not considered I assume)

What class/calculus should I use in order to get as result the 23 hours considering the DST (I have already tried different ways but I don't get it) the Period class?

Thanks for all the help...

Comment: @Quoi IST doesnt use DST at all. So you wont see the effects caused by DST

Comment: Thanks I get it and also found the answer below :)

Comment: Please ask your second question *as a second question*. Asking about Joda Time will need a fairly different (and lengthy) answer. One question per post, please!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Chances are you happen to have picked a date where daylight saving time changed in that time zone, so the day could really have been only 23 hours long. (March 25th 2012 certainly was the DST change date for Europe, e.g. [Europe/London](http://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/timezone.html?n=136). We don't know what your default time zone is though.)

If you set your date format to use UTC, you shouldn't see this effect. (It's somewhat odd to use 24:00 in a string representation, mind you.) It's not clear what your data is *meant* to represent though, or what you're trying to measure. You should work out what time zone your data is really meant to be in, if you want to work out how much time actually elapsed between those local times.

(As noted in another answer, [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sf.net) is a much better API in general - but you still need to know how to use it properly, and when trying to work out the actual elapsed time, you'd still have seen the same results here.)

Comment: What's odd in using 24:00 in string representation?

Comment: @FabianBarney: It's more usual to use 00:00 of the next day, in my experience. It's definitely permitted by ISO-8601 - just unusual to see, in my experience.

Comment: Yes it is that, thanks I haven't thought! My default time zone is "Europe/Paris". I have to measure the difference in hours between dates in different time zones but I have started writing a simple piece of code to start from the basic.

Comment: @AlexWien 24:00 is totally valid by ISO-8601 as Jon mentioned. At least in Germany this is used to express that you want the end of some day and not the beginning of the next. This makes a semantic difference in many cases.

Comment: @FabianBarney : Logically : 24:00 does not exists , 24:00 hr logically would mean that it is still the same day as on 23:59. therefore it has to be 24:01 to be the next day hence 00:01 ?? So to mark the end of current day 23:59 should be used and to mark start of next day 00:00 should be used.

Comment: @MukulGoel: No, 23:59 is still one minute *before* the end of the day, if you're talking about an instant in time (which you usually are). An equivalence between 24:00 and 00:00 the next day works fine.

Comment: @JonSkeet : there got to be an instant that marks the difference between the current day and the next day. an equivalence of 24:00 and 00:00, really? In that case another "capability" of Calendar class. by the way time is linear we formed 24 hour clock (86400000 milliseconds) if we see, then first 86400000 milliseconds make day one (00:00 - 24:00 ) then next (00:00 - 24:00) makes day 2. saying 24:00 = 00:00 ..wont that mean we are counting the same millisecond twice? and its not a 24hour clock its 23hour59minutes59seconds999milliseconds clock .. ? either Time is confusing or I am confused. :)

Comment: @MukulGoel Time things are always confusing. That's indisputable. ^^ btw: We didn't discuss leap-seconds in this context here yet. :p

Comment: @MukulGoel: There's an instant which represents the first instant of a day. The *last* instant of the day depends on the granularity. 11:59 isn't good because that's a whole minute. 11:59:59 isn't good because that's a whole second, etc. 00:00-24:00 *won't* count anything twice if you use the normal "lower bound is inclusive, upper bound is inclusive" way of dealing with ranges, so that abutting ranges cover a whole set. So for hours you'd have 00:00-01:00, 01:00-02:00 etc.

Comment: so your own words _There's an instant which represents the first instant of a day_  so, 24:00 should not be equal to 00:00 if we use 24:00 to mark end of day. one of these does not fit. Yup thats what I was trying to say last instant of day if not 11:59 , nor 11:59:59 and not 11:59:59:999 ok. But it should not be 12:00 @FabianBarney yea i know we are not taking into count leap seconds.

Comment: @MukulGoel: The instant used to provide an *exclusive upper bound* for a date is the same as the start of the next day. It's not the last instant of the day, because (being an exclusive upper bound) that would exclude the last instant of the day. 24:00 is probably only useful when it *is* used an exclusive upper bound, but in that context it makes perfect sense. I've thought a lot about date/time issues, honestly :)

Comment: Basically my point is in general is if we say 24:00 == 00:00 is true. Then we should not use 24:00 to mark end of day or 00:00 to start of day. _where did the instant go_ . I think 24:00 must not exist and there should be a function/constant in Date/Calendar/Joda that returns the end of day time.

Comment: @MukulGoel: The problem is that you keep neglecting the "exclusive upper bound" part. When it's used to mark the end of a day as an exclusive upper bound, it's fine - because it's not contained *within* the day. There's no instant missing etc. Having worked for the last three years on a date/time API, I'm entirely comfortable with this, and wouldn't want a "last instant of the day, inclusive" as you should almost never use *inclusive* upper bounds.

Comment: Yup exactly, 24:00 is exclusive upper bound. End of day is not 24:00 it lies before it amd that before depends on what granuality we talking in. For a wall clock/digital clock 23:59 or 23:59:59 . For atomic clock  23:59:59:999:999:999

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19994/discussion-between-jon-skeet-and-mukul-goel)

Comment: I think we if we had our watches as a strip marked 00:00 to ~24:00/ ~12:00 amd not a circle. It might have been more clear tp.understand time. ___the end of day and start of day does not coincide___ .time is like linear flowing river. M sorry if anywhere i sounded a bad attitude. Just interested in discussing my point.

Answer (score -1):

Must place the library file like explained below.

```
import java.util.Date;  

String dateStart = dateChooserCombo1.getText();
    String dateStop =dateChooserCombo2.getText();

    //HH converts hour in 24 hours format (0-23), day calculation
    SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");

    Date d1 = null;
    Date d2 = null;

    try {
        d1 =  format.parse(dateStart);
        d2 =  format.parse(dateStop);

        //in milliseconds
        long diff = d2.getTime() - d1.getTime();

        long diffSeconds = diff / 1000 % 60;
        long diffMinutes = diff / (60 * 1000) % 60;
        long diffHours = diff / (60 * 60 * 1000) % 24;
        long diffDays = diff / (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);

        //System.out.print(diffDays + " days, ");
        jTextField3.setText(""+diffDays);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```